# Is it possible to login to azure library(java) using the credentials used to login in azure portal?

Tags: java, azure

I am familiar with storage library and management library but they don't use the azure portal credentials to login, is there other way?

Comment: It is certainly possible to do so. Please edit your question and describe what you have done so far and what issues you're facing.

Comment: What do you mean " azure portal credentials"?

Comment: I mean the username and password to login to azure portal. Because using azure sdk you need to authenticate using access key and secret key. I want to know if we can use the username/password to login in any azure sdk and get the clientid and tenantid programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, we can Authenticate using userName and Password. For example:

```
UserTokenCredentials creds = new UserTokenCredentials(
    "<client-id>",
    "<your ad domain>",
    "<username>@contoso.com",
    "<password>",
    AzureEnvironment.Azure);
Azure.Authenticated azureAuth = Azure.authenticate(creds);
```

But please note that Microsoft does not recommend customers use the way. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Management%3A-Authentication#authenticate-using-a-username--password-combination.

Comment: However that solution will still use clientid, is there a way to just use the username and password? or just get the clientid first from username and password or other api? Been checking ways to get the client id programmatically but I'm still stuck though.

Comment: As far as I knew, we need to provide the client id. If we do not provide the client id, we cannot finish Azure AD Authentication. In fact, when we login Azure portal, the login url also includes the client id. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/

Comment: I see, well I'm good with that. Thanks Jim Xu. You're a great help. By the way, would you know if it is possible to get the client secret programmatically also? I'm not quite sure if this is possible since the client secret is hidden.

Comment: According to my research,  we can not retrieve an existing client secret (not using the Azure Portal, nor using any API). If you forget the credentials for a service principal, consider resetting the credentials(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#reset-credentials).

Comment: @drn Do you have other concern? If you have no other concern, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people.